# PHP as FastCGI and exit() function

Tags: php, fastcgi, exit

How exactly is exit() function working when in fastcgi mode?
does it finish whole instance of php process in fastcgi pool or just ends current request and return process to te pool?

if the second answer - what causes logs of this kind:

[warn] FastCGI: (dynamic) server "/php.fcgi" (pid 25113) terminated by calling exit with status '0'

??

Comment: Did the same research, found nothing. To me it seems exit() terminates not only the running script but the entire child process as you observed. Eager to read more about PHP-FPM...

Comment: Since FCGI uses a process per request it makes sense to me that the entire process is ended when calling exit().  The warning log you mention may be mitigated using exit(1) instead of exit() or die()

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this post on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/84962/php-via-fastcgi-terminated-by-calling-exit).